# Is importing headers bad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coding-style

What are your opinions on `#import`ing header files?

If I import:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

and many more headers, and only use them once in a while, is it a waste?  Does it slow down my app in any way?  More importantly, does it increase the size of my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, it doesn't do any of those things.

Headers are used by the compiler to determine how to find where various types and classes are defined. Extraneous #imports do--kinda sorta--make the process of compiling your app slower by some unmeasurably small amount.

But the resulting binary application will not be any different in size or execution speed if you have redundant headers imported in your files.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to quixoto's answer, Objective-C added the

```
#import
```

Header.  The original C header was:

```
#include
```

The difference is that #import actually checks to see if you have already included the header in your code.  If you have, the #import statement does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.